# SharePoint 2010 - multiple URLs?

Tags: sharepoint, dns, alternate-access-mappings

Currently sharepoint responds to http://sharepoint.mydomain.com.  I want it to respond to http://portal.mydomain.com also.  This is an intranet site.

Is a DNS alias and alternate access mapping all I need to do?  If not what are the necessary steps to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems so. Take a look at this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/b76cf17d-85cb-4a5e-9f7b-e0efdf438667 and this: http://dotnetengineer.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/url-aliases-for-your-sharepoint-site/. According to the second link you may want to set `Zone` setting to `Extranet`.